# a linear programming problem

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-geometry, linear-programming, real-algebraic-geometry

Recently I have a conjecture on decomposing a linear program into smaller ones. I have tested it in Mathmatica by a lot of examples. However, I cannot prove it. I will appreciate if someone can give some ideas.

> Let $f_1,\dotsc,f_r \in \mathbb{R}[x_1,...,x_n]$ ($r>n+1$) be linear functions. Then $\{f_i \ge 0|\ 1 \le i \le r \}$ has a solution if and only if $\{f_i \ge 0|\ 1 \le i \le r, i \ne j\}$ has a solution for each $j=1,\dotsc,r$.

Comment: When $n=2,r=3$, it is easy to write three half-planes who have no intersection, but every two of them have non-empty intersection.

Comment: You r = n + 1, so the gray box statement is not contradicted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The statement in the gray box is an immediate consequence of [Helly's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helly%27s_theorem): for each $i$, the set $\{ v\in\mathbb{R}^n\colon\ f_i(v)\geq 0\}$ is convex, and because of $r>n+1$, the condition given on the right-hand side of the equivalence implies that the intersection of any $n+1$ of these sets is inhabited, hence by Helly's theorem, the intersection of all the sets is inhabited too.